# Shortcuts in Xfce are not working anymore

Tags: fedora, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce

After few weeks of using Xfce I suddenly ran into following problem - my keyboard shortcuts are not working when I am using two monitors (actually one monitor and notebook itself).

When I unplug notebook from docking station, everything is working fine. It used to work correctly and I am not aware of any changes I made to settings so it must be some bad update or something.

I am running on Xfce 4.10 and Fedora 18.

P.S. It might be related to my another [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71123/window-buttons-minimize-maximaze-close-are-not-visible-on-xfce)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that the problem is solved by an another update (I am not experiencing this issue anymore). Nevertheless, thanks for tips.

Answer (score 1):

Check the contents of `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml` - that's where your keyboard short-cuts are stored. Yet most likely it is indeed because of your other problem ([Window buttons (minimize, maximaze, close) are not visible in Xfce](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71123/window-buttons-minimize-maximaze-close-are-not-visible-in-xfce)), since the window manager is the program that catches and interprets them.

Comment: Yep, there are right values so problem has to be somewhere else.

Comment: I guess it starts working once you start `xfwm4` manually, right?

Comment: Actually not, shortcuts works only without other displays connected. And it doesn't matter if the `xfwm4` is running or not.