# Window buttons (minimize, maximaze, close) are not visible in Xfce

Tags: fedora, xfce, desktop

Everytime I start my laptop my GUI is "broken" - windows don't have the top border with close, minimize and maximize buttons. I know I can run `xfwm4 --daemon` but it is really bothering to do that on every startup. It used to work without any problems until last week or so. How can this be fixed?

P.S. It might be connected with my other [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71122/shortcuts-on-xfce-are-not-working-anymore).

Comment: Window manager should be started automatically, you may have a broken session. Do you have something in `~/.config/xfce4-session/`?

Comment: From the Linux Mint forums: `As Xfce is modular by design all of those visual elements are actually separate processes. You can just start their process again to regain them. If you want to make sure that they are started again next time you login you should check the “Save session for future logins” in the logout dialog or check “Save session automatically on logout” in “Sessions and startup settings”.` Panel `xfce4-panel`, Taskbar `xftaskbar4` (Xfce 4.2 only), Window Manager `xfwm4`, Desktop `xfdesktop` (can depend on the dbus service, Xfce 4.4 only). See if starting any of those works.

Comment: @peterph: Nope, I don't have any file or folder like this in `.config/xfce*`

Comment: @Alex Thanks for tip, I am going to try that

Comment: Interesting. Has the problem arisen suddenly after an update?

Comment: @Alex No, neither of there have worked.

Comment: @peterph Yes, it suddenly stopped working after update (but I can't really tell which one)

Comment: Try with a clean profile - ideally create a new temporary user account. Or backup your `.config` and all `.*` files in your home, and try without those.

Comment: I tried that too but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that the problem is solved by an another update (I am not experiencing this issue anymore). Nevertheless, thanks for tips.